# Missing Method Exception on inheritance

Tags: c#, datatable

i have the following class that inherits from DataTable:

```
public class ExcelStaticDataTable : DataTable
{
    public List<ExcelStaticDataTable> SubTables { get; set; }
    public ExcelStaticDataTable(string tableName): base(tableName)
    {
        SubTables = new List<ExcelStaticDataTable>();
    }
}
```

Do you know why im getting a `MissingMethodException` "parameterless constructor defined for this object" when i do the following:

```
ExcelStaticDataTable table=new ExcelStaticDataTable("table1");
table.Clone();
```

Both pieces of codes are in a different dll's just for clarify. and here the stacktrace:

```
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Data.DataTable.CreateInstance()
   at System.Data.DataTable.Clone(DataSet cloneDS)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Clone()
   at System.Data.DataTable.Copy()
   at ..........cs:line 35
```

Thanks.

Comment: is the code where you are getting error in a different dll? Also can you post the complete stack?

Comment: Yes, the class ExcelStaticDataTable and Clone, are in two different dll's. It says "no parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Comment: Are both of the projects building using the same .Net framework?

Comment: yes, both using .net framework 4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the other code is using `object newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType());` as part of `Clone()`. That requires a public parameterless constructor in the default usage. Otherwise it throws a `MissingMethodException`.

Update: your update showing the stack-trace confirms this.

I suspect you can fix this by overriding the `CreateInstance` method:

```
protected override DataTable CreateInstance()
{
    return new ExcelStaticDataTable(TableName);
}
```